# Collapsing Toolbar только для одного фрагмента

Tags: android

у меня есть несколько фрагментов, между которыми я переключаюсь с помощью  Navigation Drawer. Во одном из фрагментов мне нужно использовать Collapsing Toolbar с картинкой, у других же стандарнтый Toolbar. Данный вопрос задавался ранее, но я все же не совсем разобрался. Воспользовался я вот этим способом
https://gist.github.com/groverankush/9d09fbba07879790d5395434fda1e2d4
но здесь не указан style который используется для тулбара. Возможно с этим у меня и загвоздки. Я использую стандартный style

```
<style name="AppThemes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

так выглядит Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Так выглядит Toolbar в контейнере

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.involtapp.psyans.Activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

и Так выглядит в фрагменте где мне нужно вставлять картинку

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/userapp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/usercollapse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userimg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/anon_avatar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Переходы по фрагментам осуществляются как и в указанной выше ссылке, думаю вставлять этот код не имеет смысла, т.к уже на входе я получаю следующую ошибку

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Если же поставить style NoActionBar, ошибка не вылезает, но и тулбар уже не появляется

Comment: Судя по последнему абзацу, вы не делаете это `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` в `onCreate` активности

Comment: данная строка присутствует, и как раз на ней приложение крашится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы ставите отдельно `Toolbar` в `layout`, то нужно к `activity` ставить тему `NoActionBar`.

Замените ваш стиль `AppThemes` так:

```
<style name="AppThemes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
```

И этот стиль вы ставите на всё приложение, т.е. в `<application>` т.е. так:

```
android:theme="@style/AppThemes"
```

Дальше добавьте такой стиль в `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppThemes.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

Этот стиль уже добавляете к отдельному `activity`, в которое вы добавили `Toolbar` в `layout`

Добавьте в манифесте к `activity` где вы отдельно добавили `Toolbar`:

```
android:theme="@style/AppThemes.NoActionBar"
```